# VMware issue, machine will not boot up

Tags: vmware

Last week I was using VMware Workstation Pro (Registered) 15 and it was working seamlessly. But now this week rolls around and I try to boot up on of my ubuntu machines and I get this error:

```
This virtual machine failed to switch to 64 bit mode. This failure might be due to a lack of available memory on the host.

Module 'Monitor' power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine
```

In a little popup box. And when I ran this, the ubuntu machine only needed 700 mb of ram. I have 11 GB free.
But then it says monitor module can't power on, I tried messing with those settings and still nothing worked.

The reason that I am on StackOverFlow is because when I tried to find support on VMwares website, I found nothing at all.

Comment: there's currently a open [thread](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2943825) in vmware forums as well on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/g4e0o1/vmware_error_while_powering_on_module_monitor/). Seems to be related to a windows update, but no fix for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I disabled the 'Windows Hypervisor' and 'Virtual Machine Platform'  in 'Windows Features', after restart the error disappeared.

Comment: I don't think you need to disable both of them, if your VMware version is >= `15.5.5` . The `Virtual Machine Platform` is required for the Windows Subsystem for Linux (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). For me, `Windows Hypervisor` was already disabled. I just enabled the `Hyper-V` functionality (source: https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/vmware-workstation-now-supports-hyper-v-mode.html) and restarted Windows.